# pymsql insert insert_id returns 0 using phpmyadmin

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-insert, pymysql

So i have a phpmyadmin sql database.

I also have a locally hosted mysql database, and my code needs to talk to both of them.
For the stuff on my local, when i run an insert call on a table, i can call my held connection:

self.connection.insert_id()

and get the id of the last inserted item.

However, when I do this to my phpmyadmin database, the insert_id ALWAYS return 0.
The code is just:

```
cmd = 'INSERT INTO meal ({0}) VALUES ({1})'.format(','.join(keys), ','.join(values))
```

and the insert works, but insert_id returns 0, even though via phpmyadmin i can see that the 'id' key for this table is:
INT(11) null is not checked, auto increment is on, and its got the gold key primary key icon

So im not really sure whats going on - is this a bug, or am i doing something incredibly stupid?

Thanks!

EDIT:
As a side note, the items that i insert DO have ID keys that are auto incrementing appropirately, just not getting returned :(

Answer (score 0):

Heres something strange - I notice if i do EITHER of:

```
my_id= self.connection.cursor().rownumber
```

or

```
my_id= self.connection.insert_id()
```

it gives me 0 every time, HOWEVER if i do:

```
        my_id= self.connection.cursor().rownumber
        if my_id== 0:
            my_id= self.connection.insert_id()
```

I get the correct result... crazy?